# pthread_create only if data is available on socket

Tags: c, sockets, select-function

I have server that is sending udp datagrams to client and receiving NACK datagrams from client if packet is lost. I want to create thread that will process every NACK packet but I want to create thread only if I have something to receive from the client. For that I thought to use select , if there is something on socket then create new thread and call recvfrom fucntion. I define timeval struct and fill it with 0 because I don't want to wait , I want that select "listening on socket " whole the time while server is sending but select always return me 0 ....is there any solution maybe with different idea how to sending and receiving parallel?

```
int main (void) {

    struct timeval tv;
    tv.tv_sec = 0;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;

    fd_set readfds;
    FD_ZERO(&readfds);

    // Create the socket
    if((sd = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {
        printf("Server socket could not be created : %s\n",strerror(errno));
        return 0;
    }


    // Non-blocking socket
    fcntl(sd,F_SETFL,O_NONBLOCK);

    FD_ZERO(&readfds);
    FD_SET(sd,&readfds);

    //Allow multiple applications to receive datagrams that are destined to the same local port number.
    if(setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &optval, sizeof(optval)) == -1){ 
        printf("Setsockopt error: %s", strerror(errno));
        return 1;      
    }  

    // Initialize the group sockaddr structure with a multicast address of 226.1.1.1 and port 5555. 
    memset((char *) &multiaddr, 0, sizeof(multiaddr));
    multiaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    multiaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IP_GROUP);
    multiaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT_NUM);  

    // Fill the structure udp_srv with informations like multicast address,port number and socket
    strcpy(udp_srv.peer_address,inet_ntoa(multiaddr.sin_addr));
    udp_srv.peer_port = multiaddr.sin_port;
    udp_srv.udp_sd = sd;

    if((fd = open("text.txt",O_RDONLY , 0777))== -1) {
        printf("Error while opening txt file!\n",strerror(errno));
        return 1;       
    } else {         
        while(1) {            
            sleep(1);    
            if((numRead = read(fd,tmp,512)) != 0) {               
                tmp[numRead]='\0';
                strcpy(pack.buffer,tmp);
                //function for sending data until EOF !     
                sent = data_sent(udp_srv,&pack);      
            } else {               
                sent = last_data_sent(udp_srv,&pack);       
                close(sd);
                exit(1);
            }         
            rv = select(sd + 1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);          

            if(rv > 0) {

                // Create a new thread and call recvfrom in nack_processing function !
                if(pthread_create(&cln_thread, NULL, nack_processing, (void *) &arg)){
                    printf("Pthrad create errorr\n",strerror(errno));
                    continue;
                }
            }     
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: where is your code for `select` ????

Comment: Sorry I forgot , code is updated in question above

Answer (score 0):

Few suggestions.

change `if(rv == 1)` to `if(rv > 0)` and provide some time

```
struct timeval tv;
tv.tv_sec = 5;


fd_set readfds;
rv = select(sd + 1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
rv = select(sd + 1, &readfds, (fd_set *)0, (fd_set *)0, &tv);
```

Try with that

Comment: But problem is that I can not provide time , 5 sec is too much for my application that will be in real time ...I thought maybe select can work to listen whole the time if there is something to receive while server is sending whole the time....any idea?

Comment: code is updated again but not whole because it has more c files and headers but you can see the concept from this main ...

Answer (score 0):

At least under Linux you need to **re**-initialise the `struct timeval` parameter to `select()` before each call, as it might have been modified by the previous call to `select()`.

```
...

while(1)
{
  sendto();

  {
    struct timeval tv = 
    {
      0, 0
    };

    rv = select(sd + 1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
  }

  ...
```